# KNN with scikit-learn: how to obtain the distance matrix using NaN euclidean metric?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nan, knn, imputation

I am using sklearn.impute.KNNImputer on a dataset with missing values. I want to try several numbers of neighbors.

To instantiate the KNNImputer, the number of neighbors should be specified. The distance matrix is then computed with `.fit()` method. I could save computational time by doing the imputation with several numbers of neighbors *after* I have computed the distance matrix.

**How can I compute the distance matrix without fitting, using sklearn?**

Below is toy example. It takes ~2 minutes to run, but each imputation requires ~120ms. If I had the distance matrix, I could perform the various imputations much faster.

```
import time
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from sklearn.impute import KNNImputer

np.random.seed(666)

nb_lines = 2000
nb_columns = 8
miss_rate = 0.1

data = np.random.normal(size=(nb_lines, nb_columns))
miss_mask_temp = np.random.uniform(size=(nb_lines, nb_columns))
miss_mask = (miss_mask_temp < miss_rate)
nb_missing = np.sum(miss_mask)

data2 = np.copy(data)
data2[miss_mask] = np.nan

nb_neighbours = np.arange(1, 1001)
store_rmse = np.zeros(shape=nb_neighbours.shape)
store_time = np.zeros(shape=nb_neighbours.shape)
for n in range(nb_neighbours.shape[0]):
    if (n+1)%50==0:
        print(n+1, end=" ", flush=True)
        if (n+1)%500==0:
            print()
    t1 = time.time()
    nb_n = nb_neighbours[n]
    myKNN = KNNImputer(n_neighbors=nb_n, weights="uniform", metric="nan_euclidean")
    myKNN.fit(data2)
    impute_knn = myKNN.transform(data2)
    rmse = np.sqrt(np.sum(((data - impute_knn) ** 2) * miss_mask) / nb_missing)
    store_rmse[n] = rmse
    t2 = time.time()
    store_time[n] = t2 - t1
```

Answer (score 2):

I am going to answer my own question: we want to use `sklearn.metrics.pairwise.nan_euclidean_distances`.
Have a look here: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.pairwise.nan_euclidean_distances.html